# :last-child selector not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, html5

my requirement: I want to hide last `<hr>` in the template under for loop.

**HTML:**

```
<div  class="article">
   <template if:true={List} for:each={List} for:item="k" >
      <div key={k.Id} role="" >
         <span >
            <a data-id={k.Id} class="slds-p-horizontal_large slds-p-vertical_medium"  style="font-weight: lighter;display:flex; ">{k.Question</a>
         </span>
         <hr>
      </div>
   </template>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.article hr:last-child {
   display: none;
}
```

I'm unable to hide last hr in UI

Answer (score 2):

Your `<hr />` needs to be outside the inner `<div>` for it to be considered the `:last-child` element, as that selector only considers the last child of the given parent, and, as written in your code, it's a grandchild element.

```
<template>
    <div class="article">
        <template if:true={List} for:each={List} for:item="k">
            <div key={k.Id} role="">
                <span >
            <a data-id={k.Id} class="slds-p-horizontal_large slds-p-vertical_medium"  style="font-weight: lighter;display:flex; ">{k.Question}</a>
         </span>
            </div>
            <hr key={k.Id} />
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

Or, you can fix your CSS (given your original template):

```
.article div:last-child hr {
  display: none;
}
```

Alternatively, consider skipping the `<hr />` and doing it in straight CSS:

```
.article > div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.article > div:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

[Demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/V0i7Hl4uXnhoGICKprlE/src/app.css).